# "...Enough that one can do" for "...enough to do" in AE

Tags: american-english

In AE, can the phrasal turn "...enough that one can do" be used interchangeablyn with "...enough to do" in just about every which context?

> *Sam is spiritually **strong enough that he can** stand with Nephy*... [source](https://ojs.lib.byu.edu/spc/index.php/JBMRS/article/viewFile/19794/18361)
>
> *He's **smart enough that he can** do anything he sets his mind to*...
>   [source](http://www.examiner.com/article/rush-ron-howard-continues-to-struggle-to-get-back-into-good-form)
>
> *He's also **tall enough that he can** drink from the sink*... [source](http://fr.eonline.com/news/509268/meet-freddy-the-great-dane-the-tallest-dog-in-britain-and-possibly-the-tallest-dog-in-the-world)

Answer (score 2):

We usually say

> Goldcake is a pony with wings that aren't quite strong, but strong enough to fly up to 5 ft. above.

So I guess my answer to your question is *yes* ("strong enough to fly" vs "enough strong to fly").

And I don't think the phrase "but enough strong that ..." is that commonly used.

And please never ever use the phrase "up to at least", see the first panel of this xkcd comic:

[image: xkcd up to and more]

Comment: Sure. I don't see any fault to that as far as the way I speak and write in English is concerned. The example actually was a sourced one. I surely wouldn't have used "at least" in that construction either. ;)